# tool to create objects from XML Web Service Schema

Tags: c#, asp.net, xsd

I work a lot with external Web Services, and I need to create an object (class) based on that document, so I can use that object across my web application.

My question is simple, is there a way that I can create/generate an object using only the XML provided from the schema?

kind'a [wscompile tool](http://huihoo.org/openweb/java_web_services_tutorial/JAXRPC6.html)

Would save a lot of hours to everyone :)

**Added after first 2 responses:**

maybe you are right, but can't test it

Maybe it is me, but How can I do that for:

http://obo.par.se/jboss-net/services/DocumentFactory?WSDL

in the manual it says that

> "If you build a web service from
> Visual Studio, you have to use the
> following as a WSDL source: "OBO -
> Modified to work with Visual
> Studio.wsdl"

Shouldn't a "Web Service" be the same whatever language we choose to create and consume it? ins't that the point of Web Services?

I even copied the Schema and saved [here](http://www.balexandre.com/temp/xmlShemaTest.xml) so I can imported from VS, but when I imported as Web Reference I do not get the Object, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By creating a web reference in Visual Studio, proxy classes are created for you. That might be what you need.

Comment: added more info into the original question

Comment: got it, I just need to add a web reference and use the ref name and the object , thxs

Comment: When I try to do this, Disco.exe complains about the format of the SOAP.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understand your question .... Visual Studio has been able to create proxy clases to  WSDL for a few releases .. google: visual studio wsdl proxy

Comment: added more info into the original question